# Xbox music app not showing album art

Tags: xbox-music, nokia-lumia-630

Xbox music app unable to show album art of stored songs while in Zbox app I am abel to view them. Why? Can we fix it?

Comment: Where are the songs from? Are they DRM-protected? What format are they in? How is the album art stored - embedded in the music files or as separate image files?

Comment: My songs are not DRM-protected,simple mp3 files, ID3v2.3 tag is used,can't say album image is embedded or separate,but i can say image is of jpeg format with resolution of 500x500 pixels. Codec used MPEG 1 Layer III.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the number of songs it takes some time until all covers are visible. It took several day's with about 6,000 songs on the older 820.

Comment: I have only 25 songs,so I don't think it's a refresh problem. All songs downloaded from mixradio shows album art,so I think xbox music app supports only low resolution album art. Anybody can confirm it? All my album art's resolution is 500x500. One thing to be noted in Tag Editor app I can see all missing album arts.